# No database connection in rails console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My rails application works fine when I run `rake db:migrate` but the problem occurs when I try to start the rails console.

```
2.0.0p247 :003 > User
 => User(no database connection)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

simple solution:
The console probably does have a database connection but is reporting that it doesn't.

To see if that's true, make a query in the console.

```
User.count
```

That fixed the false positive warning for me and a colleague.

or

Use `Model.connection` to establish a connection.

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: In light of the comment by gmile [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21062685/1412858) and as per rails github issues [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12804#issuecomment-29885300) this answer should be unmarked as accepted

Answer (score 86):

That is due to ActiveRecord establishing the connection lazily starting `4.0`. Just don't worry about it.

After it's established the first time, you'll start seeing the expected output. Try this:

```
2.1.4 :001 > User
# => User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection)

2.1.4 :001 > User.count
# => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" ...

2.1.4 :001 > User
# => User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, ...)
```

Comment: How do you *not* lazily create your connection? What benefits does that have?

Comment: @Trip I'm assuming it saves memory within an application. Why load something that you haven't used into memory, deal with it when the time comes.

Answer (score 24):

To restore the behavior of ActiveRecord models displaying their column information immediately after the console has loaded, here is one workaround:

```
# config/application.rb
console do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection
end
```

Comment: This automates the process nice one

Comment: Nice! Takes care of that annoyance. I put this in `environments/development.rb` just to limit its application, and it seems to be working fine from there.

Answer (score 4):

That isn't a problem. All that's happening is the connection is not instantiated until it's needed.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.