# weird rails4.1 has_many_through association bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many-through

I'm using rails 4.1.12 and tried to create has_many_through association recently.

My role model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: roles
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users
  
  has_many :roles_responsibilities
  has_many :responsibilities, through: :roles_responsibilities

end
```

Responsibility model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: responsibilities
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  action_name     :string(255)
#  controller_name :string(255)
#  created_at      :datetime
#  updated_at      :datetime
#

class Responsibility < ActiveRecord::Base
  
  has_many :roles_responsibilities
  has_many :roles, through: :roles_responsibilities

end
```

and

Roles_responsibilities

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: roles_responsibilities
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  role_id           :integer
#  responsibility_id :integer
#  user_id           :integer
#  user_type         :string(255)
#  created_at        :datetime
#  updated_at        :datetime
#

class RolesResponsibility < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :role
belongs_to :responsibility
end
```

I believe I did correctly but getting a strange

```
 NameError: undefined local variable or method `  ' for Role (call 'Role.connection' to establish a connection):Class
```

in model.

I checked all spelling and syntax but not sure why i'm getting this error?

could anyone help me to find the mistakes?

Comment: How are you trying to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because ActiveRecord has lazy loading for your database connection. If you run the query again, it should work just fine, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062134/no-database-connection-in-rails-console) SO question. You can double-check by running something like `Role.count`

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it helped.